# Where do you extend classes in your rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, environment

Just about to extend the Array class with the following extension:

```
class Array
  def shuffle!
    size.downto(1) { |n| push delete_at(rand(n)) }
    self
  end
end
```

However, I was wondering where a good place to keep these sort of extensions. I was thinking  environment.rb or putting in its own file in the initializers directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I usually follow the ActiveSupport convention, which would be to place them in `lib/core_ext/#{class}.rb` - in this case, `lib/core_ext/array.rb`.  As John Hyland notes, you can then require the file explicitly where needed, or put a require statement in initializers.

Comment: This seems like a better answer than mine, so I'm going to delete my answer (and start writing my apps this way).